# Why is MDX with Next.JS missing IDs on my elements?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, mdxjs

I'm mapping custom HTML to some markdown elements for my site.
For some reason, in `genId`, the build fails because props can be empty string/null. However, this only happens in production build and everything works perfectly locally.

I've also noticed that upon refresh, the ids are *all* missing, whereas on initial page load from a separate page, they are present.

The intention of this code is to take the data off a markdown heading and convert it to a CSS ID.

## Components

```
import postStyling from "../../styles/post/Index.module.css";

const genId = (props) => {
  console.log(props);
  if (props === undefined || props === "") return "";
  return props.toLowerCase().replaceAll(" ", "_");
};

const MDXComponents = {
  p: (props) => (
    <p {...props} className={postStyling["content"]}>
      {props.children}
    </p>
  ),
  h1: (props) => (
    <h1
      {...props}
      id={genId(props.children)}
      className={`${postStyling["main-heading"]}`}
    >
      {props.children}
    </h1>
  ),
  h2: (props) => (
    <h2
      {...props}
      className={postStyling["post-header"]}
      id={genId(props.children)}
    >
      {props.children}
    </h2>
  ),
  h3: (props) => (
    <h3
      {...props}
      className={postStyling["post-header"]}
      id={genId(props.children)}
    >
      {props.children}
    </h3>
  ),
  h4: (props) => (
    <h4
      {...props}
      className={postStyling["post-header"]}
      id={genId(props.children)}
    >
      {props.children}
    </h4>
  ),
};

export default MDXComponents;
```

### Refresh Same Page

[image]

### Clicking from Home Page

[image]

### Component

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

// Custom Components
import BlogHeader from "./BlogHeader";

import MDXComponents from "../mdx/MDXComponents";
import { MDXRemote } from "next-mdx-remote";

// CSS
import styles from "../../styles/admin/Panel.module.css";
import post from "../../styles/post/Index.module.css";

const PostTitle = ({ title, date }) => {
  return (
    <div className={post["title"]}>
      <span>{title}</span>
      <span className={post["date"]}>{date}</span>
    </div>
  );
};

const TableOfContents = ({ toc }) => {
  return (
    <div className={post["toc"]}>
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: toc }}></div>
    </div>
  );
};

function Post({ content, metadata, toc }) {
  let icon = metadata["type"] == "video" ? "" : "";
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <BlogHeader />
      <PostTitle title={`${icon} ${metadata.title}`} date={metadata.date} />
      <h2 id={post["toc-header"]}>Table of Contents</h2>
      <TableOfContents toc={toc} />
      <MDXRemote {...content} components={MDXComponents} />
    </div>
  );
}
export default Post;
```